# css файл - призрак

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой - страница использует .css файл, который на этой странице ни где не вызывается.
Это простая login page предыдущая версия которой использовала bootstrap.css.
Я убрал все упоминания bootstrap.css со страницы, но она продолжает загружать этот файл с сервера и применять стили к элементам.
На странице абсолютно точно нет link элементов вызывающих этот файл но я вижу его на вкладках Sources и Network.
На вкладке Elements -> Styles я вижу:
[image: .row { bootstrap.css:238]

Я проверил page source, я скопировал outerHTML для всего елемента `<html>`, вставил его в блокнот и просмотрел каждую строку и там абсолютно точно не вызывается bootstrap.css. Вообще никаких его упоминаний нет, однако он как-то загружатся и стили применяются.
КАК?

Comment: 1 вариант - кэш браузера. Надо почистить. 2 - какой-нибудь js может подгружать его. 3 - если это фреймворк - то может быть в ассетах подключение где-то ещё. Посмотрите путь до этой css'ки и глобально в проекте поищите ещё на наличие этого слова

Comment: мне кажется кэш - это вряд-ли (чтобы наверняка откройте консоль и кликните правой кнопкой на иконку обновить страничку, выберите "очистка кэш и жесткая перезагрузка" - если используете хром), но скорее всего у вас подключена еще какая-то страничка, ну например шапка сайта, и в этом файле может быть линк на злосчастный css

Answer (score 0):

Кажется разобрался. Таки кэш, но не браузера (его я чистил), а сервер мудрит.
На странице подключается .css файл, в котором импортится другой .css файл, внутри которого был раньше импорт этого злосчастного bootstrap.css.
Для файла на странице я добавил параметр с версией и сервер отдаёт именно обновлённой файл, а вот тот файл, который импортился, остался со старым именем и его сервер не обновил, а продолжает отдавать из своего кэша.
Как то так:

```
<link href="styles.css?v=2">
  |--> @import 'reset.css' <-- этот файл я обновил, но имя осталось старое
    |--> @import 'bootstrap.css'<-- этого импорта нет в новом файле reset.css
                                    но есть в закэшированном старом и сервер его грузит
```

Вобщем, оказалось, что никакой мистики нет :)
Всем спасибо за помощь.